# MikTex installation stops showing a list of options

Tags: installation, miktex, texstudio

I had to change my computer with WIn10, where I had TexStudio+MikTex.
On the new computer which still uses Win10 I am reinstalling MikTex and TexStudio, but MikTex installer (basic-miktex-22.7-x64.exe) stops showing a list of options "Usage: setupwiz [OPTIONS]". It seems that I should install it manually! Is that right? If so why the manual doesn't mention that?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just run as administrator, and it will be solved!